# How to convert row from bigtable to Avro generic records

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-bigtable

I am reading bigtable in my Pcollection and then trying to convert the read records to Avro Generic Records .Is it possible to directly change read from big table to generic records without writing any function in the pCollection ?

For example : i am trying to do something like below

```
 pipeline
    .apply("Read from Bigtable", read)
    .apply("Transform to generic records using Avro.IO", AvroIO.<<>> 
     (read));
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to write [Generic Records](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/api/java/org/apache/avro/generic/GenericRecord.html?is-external=true) with [AvroIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.9.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/AvroIO.html), you'll need to provide an Avro [Schema](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/api/java/org/apache/avro/Schema.html?is-external=true), which I believe is incompatible with the output from BigtableIO, so this is not possible without a transformation between BigtableIO and AvroIO.